Git "detected dubious ownership in repository" that doesn't exist on machine
I'm working on a repository that I've been using for several years.  The local clone on my machine is in ~/dev/repo_name.  The remote has it stored in /var/git/repo_name.
All of a sudden this afternoon (with no users of the repository knowingly having changed anything) I am getting
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/var/git/repo_name'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory /var/git/repo_name 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I have tried the suggested fix, as well as other variants found on SE, but none have helped.
ssh-ing into the remote finds that the folder ownership is unchanged (it's a group called "git users" which includes the user I use to connect via git.)
What can I try next?

I ran into the same issue recently and I assume it was also caused by a git update on the server side.
The error effectively read
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/home/.../gitrepo/.git'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

        git config --global --add safe.directory /home/.../gitrepo/.git
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

In my case, I had already configured safe.directory locally and on the server side safe.directory=/home/.../gitrepo.
The fix I found is to configure safe.directory to * on the remote side (git config --global safe.directory '*'). I haven't fully investigated it, but I assume that the local configuration doesn't matter at all, and only the server side configuration is checked. Additionally, note that even though I had safe.directory already configured with the specified repository, only setting the config to * fixed the problem for me.

For "All of a sudden this afternoon", maybe it is caused by upgrade of the git package at 2024-05-28 at your git server side.
e.g.: ubuntu 20.04
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/focal/main/updates/git
Changelog
Version: 1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.12   2024-05-28 17:08:14 UTC
git (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.12) focal-security; urgency=medium

SECURITY UPDATE: Arbitrary code execution

debian/patches/CVE-2024-32004.patch: detect dubious ownership of
local repositories in path.c, setup.c, setup.h.
CVE-2024-32004



ubuntu 22.04:
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/jammy/main/security/git
Following command could show the version of your git
$ dpkg -l git

Solution:
On git server side, you could manually build the git from offical git source code, e.g.: tag v2.25.1, which will not have the security patch:
https://github.com/git/git

it seems git added a feature where it made it so only the top-level owner (not group) of a directory can safely interact using git with the git directory. More discussion here on SO: "git submodule update" failed with 'fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at...'
Fix:
as the error message hints at. one must:
ssh into the git server as the git user
run git config --global --add safe.directory /var/git/repo_name
run a git fetch command from your local machine to check that this has worked

This tells git that for your user, /var/git/repo_name is a safe directory to work withIt adds the following to your ~/.gitconfig:
[safe]
directory = /var/git/repo_name

There is Bitbucket blog post containing details about a recent git version release with stricter checks for the owner of the top-level git directory. From the relevant git v2.30.3 commit there is the following detail:

It poses a security risk to search for a git directory outside of the
directories owned by the current user.

and

This new default behavior is obviously incompatible with the concept of
shared repositories, where we expect the top-level directory to be owned
by only one of its legitimate users.

For the scenario of the OP where there are connecting to the remote git repo as a different user to the owner of the remote git directory (group membership does not count). The directory exception needs to be added via the safe-directory key in system config e.g.
sudo git config --system --add safe.directory /var/git/repo_name 


From my personal experience: This problem occurs, if multiple users of a unix system (have never tried this in windows), push/pull a remote git repository with different user names.
A git repository consists of several files and folders inside the repository folder. If any of these files are not read/writeable by the current SSH-User this error would occur.
If you just want to fix this, the following commands should help:
chown -R youruser:gitgroup /var/git/repo_name This will reset the owner/group of all files in the repository. You may also issue a chmod, in case something modified the file permissions.
If you are interested in the cause, list all files with their user/group and check if there is another user:group combination than expected.
I think this issue is also the reason, why git hosting solutions (e.g. github, gitlab, gitea), share the common user git for all git cloning via ssh.

Thank you.  This wasn't relevant in my case.
